# Error 404 not found pivot4j file in the Pentaho BiServer

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, pentaho

I've download pivot4j and install from Pentaho Marketplace
After restart tomcat server,
in the web browser console.log while opening the bi-server,
it show red error as following.

`GET http://192.168.1.116:8080/pentaho/mantle/home/properties/config_en.properties?_=1414732010505 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
GET http://192.168.1.116:8080/pentaho/mantle/home/properties/config_en-US.properties?_=1414732010506 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
GET http://192.168.1.116:8080/pentaho/mantle/home/properties/messages_en.properties?_=1414732010508 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
GET http://192.168.1.116:8080/pentaho/mantle/home/properties/messages_en-US.properties?_=1414732010509 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
GET http://192.168.1.116:8080/pentaho/undefined.properties?_=1414732010510 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
GET http://192.168.1.116:8080/pentaho/undefined_en.properties?_=1414732010511 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
GET http://192.168.1.116:8080/pentaho/undefined_en-US.properties?_=1414732010512 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
GET http://192.168.1.116:8080/pentaho/api/repos/pivot4j/webapp/resources/pivot4j/i18n/messages.properties.properties?_=1414732010513 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
GET http://192.168.1.116:8080/pentaho/api/repos/pivot4j/webapp/resources/pivot4j/i18n/messages.properties_en.properties?_=1414732010514 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
GET http://192.168.1.116:8080/pentaho/api/repos/pivot4j/webapp/resources/pivot4j/i18n/messages.properties_en-US.properties?_=1414732010515 404 (Not Found)`

And there is no pivot4j in File -> New menu.

I've no idea how to fix this... I have lag skilled of java tomcat application.

Please advice me.

(Pentaho 5.0.1-stable, pivot4j 1.0-SNAPSHOT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had a similar error, reinstalling the pivot4j worked for me!

Comment: Ok, it's now working. (I also uninstall plugin IvyDD)